# How to set shift in String.format dynamically?

Tags: java

Is it possible to set shift nor by default but programmatically? I mean if I have a code

```
System.out.format("%-d%d", shift, value);
```

it returns `java.util.MissingFormatWidthException`. Instead of error I want to set the shift dynamically.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can create your format String on the fly, but it has to be a two-step process:

```
String formatString = "%-" + shift + "d";
System.out.format(formatString, value);
```

or

```
String formatString = String.format("%%-%sd", shift); // %% for the single %
System.out.format(formatString, value);
```

or as Christian notes

```
System.out.format("%-" + shift + "d", value);
```

Comment: Could it be `System.out.format("%-" + shift + "d", value);`?

Comment: I get `Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: -0d`

Comment: @barbara: it won't work for `0`. you'll need an if block for this.

Comment: @barbara: I didn't know that 0 was a possibility.